# How to create a memory pool with arbitrary number of (compile time determined) containers?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic

I have a memory pool that looks like so:

```
template<typename TreeType>
class LeafMemoryPool
{
public:
    void stealNodes(TreeType& tree);
    Leaf* getNode();
private:
    std::vector<Leaf*> mLeafs;
}
```

In my program I have different `TreeType`s, like `FloatTree` and `Vec3Tree`, and I create a memory pool for each tree type. However, passing these around is a little annoying, and I would prefer a single memory pool that handles all of the different types. Also, I might need to add additional types in the future and I would like for it to be as dynamic as possible. Is this something that could be done with variadic templates? I have never used them before, and I do not know if this is what they could be used for.

The scenario I'm thinking of could be written in pseudo-code as

```
template<typename... TreeTypes>
class MemoryPool
{
public:
    // The template is only valid if the same type was declared
    // in TreeTypes above
    template<typename TreeType>
    void stealNodes(TreeType& tree)
    {
        // Somehow need to access the right std::vector that
        // stores TreeType::Leaf. This function will be called
        // a lot, and needs to be determined at compile time
        // for it to be useful.
    }

    template<typename TreeType>
    typename TreeType::Leaf* getNode();
private:
    // One for each TreeType in TreeTypes.
    // The leaf type can be deduced by
    // typename TreeType::Leaf
    std::vector<LeafArg1*> mLeafsForArg1;
    std::vector<LeafArg2*> mLeafsForArg2;
    ...
}
```

Everything above should be able to be determined at compile time. Can I solve this with some C++ template magic?

Comment: std::tuple will do it

Comment: Something like `template <typename ...Ts> using MemoryPools = std::tuple<LeafMemoryPool<Ts>...>;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that. I'm going to give you a solution for a simplified version of your class. You should be able to trivially adjust this solution for your class. Tested with gcc 6.1.1.

```
#include <vector>

class A {};
class B {};
class C {};

template<typename ...Args> class pool;

template<typename firstArg, typename ...Args>
class pool<firstArg, Args...> : public pool<Args...> {

 public:

    using pool<Args...>::stealNodes;

    void stealNodes(firstArg &tree)
    {
    }

private:
    std::vector<firstArg *> leafs;

};

template<> class pool<> {

public:

    void stealNodes(); // Undefined
};


void foo()
{
    pool<A, B, C> pool;

    A a;
    B b;
    C c;

    pool.stealNodes(a);
    pool.stealNodes(b);
    pool.stealNodes(c);
}
```

Comment: I've read this a couple of times now, but I'm still not exactly sure what is happening. What is the purpose of the subclassing? And how does `pool.stealNodes(a)` properly get determined to the "right" `std::vector`?

Comment: @pingul operator overloading.  Sam, `getNode` is a bit tricky, you might want to include it.  Maybe a most-derived `pool<Ts...>` helper, rename your type to `pool_impl`, and give `pool<Ts...>` a `template<class T> typename T::Leaf* getNode(){ return getNode( tag<TreeType> ); }`?  Where `pool_impl<firstArg, Args...>` implements `getNode( tag<firstArg> )`?

Comment: Oh, and to clean it up, I'd split the inheritance from the implementation.  Like `struct simple_pool<T>` (with the vector and stealNodes function etc) and `struct pool<firstArg, Args...>: simple_pool<firstArg>, pool<Args...>{ using simple_pool<firstArg>::stealNodes; using pool<Args...>::stealNodes;` simply because the error messages are easier to read in most compilers.

Comment: @Yakk I've tried implementing your recommendations, but my knowledge of templates seems to be a little limited. If possible, please provide an example as a standalone answer.

Comment: As @Yakk noted earlier, `getNode` would be difficult to implement. I made a solution by changing the function slightly to `void getNode(typename firstArg::Leaf*)` instead, as operator overloading does some magic in this case as well. Would another solution be preferred/better? As of know it kind of makes sense, as I somehow have to declare with type of leaf I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<typename... TreeTypes>
class MemoryPool
{
public:
    // The template is only valid if the same type was declared
    // in TreeTypes above
    template<typename TreeType>
    void stealNodes(TreeType& tree)
    {
        // Somehow need to access the right std::vector that
        // stores TreeType::Leaf. This function will be called
        // a lot, and needs to be determined at compile time
        // for it to be useful.
        using leaf_type = typename TreeType::Leaf;
        using vec_type = std::vector<leaf_type>;
        auto& pool = std::get<vec_type>(_leaves);
    }

    template<typename TreeType>
    typename TreeType::Leaf* getNode()
    {
        using leaf_type = typename TreeType::Leaf;
        using vec_type = std::vector<leaf_type>;
        auto& pool = std::get<vec_type>(_leaves);

        // pool is now a reference to your vector
    }
private:
    // One for each TreeType in TreeTypes.
    // The leaf type can be deduced by
    // typename TreeType::Leaf

    std::tuple< std::vector<typename TreeTypes::Leaf> ... > _leaves;
};
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) will `auto& pool` be binded at compile time, or is any run-time lookup done? (2) Will there be any problem (memory wise) by storing dynamic objects in a `std::tuple`?

Comment: 1) compile time, 2) none at all.

Comment: Good answer, but @Sam's solution makes `stealNodes` a non-template function, which gives better error messages and deals with derived `TreeType`s better.

Comment: @Yakk I don't know. I think either would look equally horrid in a debugger. For the simple case it's as long as it's broad. At least this one is only one level of derivation deep. What if other data members/non-virtual functions were added? The mutliply-derived version could become a nightmare very quickly.